# How to layout a view whose frame depends of the orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Consider a view that has to aligned to the bottom of the screen and whose width must fill the screen.

Additionally, the height of the view depends of the orientation. In portrait orientation the height of the view must be 200px and in landscape the height must be 100px.

What is the best way to do this without assuming anything about the parent view size (ie: don't know if it has status bar or not, maybe there's a tab bar, etc.)?

This is my current code, that doesn't work:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    CGSize myViewSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 200);
    // Align bottom
    float myViewY = self.view.frame.origin.y + self.view.frame.size.height - myViewSize.height;
    myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, myViewY, myViewSize.width, myViewSize.height);
    myView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
}


- (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    BOOL landscape = UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
    myView.frame = CGRectMake(myView.frame.origin.x, myView.frame.origin.y, myView.frame.size.width, landscape ? 100 : 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using UIWindow object as given below:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].screen.applicationFrame.size.height
```

Apple documentation for applicationFrame reads as below:

This property contains the screen bounds minus the area occupied by the status bar, if it is visible. Using this property is the recommended way to retrieve your application’s initial window size. The rectangle is specified in points

Comment: Can you elaborate further how to use the screen frame in the above example?

Comment: Also, what happens if there's a toolbar or a tabbar?